# Creating a formula to determine popularity

Tags: php, math, formula

For my browse page i need to create a forumula so that images that are popular will be shown first. Now the only thing i can really base this of is the how many likes a image has received on my website.

Is there anything else you would recommend to add to my website to improve this formula? I could create a views function that is hidden from the user as i do not want it to be abused.

Also how would i create this in PHP even if it was just based on likes?

would it just be something like

```
$totaluploads = 44;
$currentimagelikes = 12;
$score = $totaluploads / $currentimagelikes x 100;
```

Lastly would i make a function that generates this on page load? Or save it in a database and run a cron job to update it every x minutes?

REOPENED.
Can anyone give me a example on how i can make a forumla for this? This is what i have tried.

```
$daysold = 0;
$likes = 1;
$ageminus = $daysold *0.5;
$age = $likes - $daysold;

$score = $age / $likes * 100;
echo round($score)."%";
```

But if a image is just uploaded then it will give it 100% popularity? :/

Comment: You can generate it when page loads. It'd have sense to save this rating in db if you had to read just that score.

Comment: But it wouldn't be that large of a function. Would it put that much strain on resources?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the image views/impressions count too.
If you have all your counts like totaluploads,currentimagelikes etc. at the time of page generation then you can calculate score dynamically Or else you will always have an option to save score in database and update it every x minutes.

Comment: Is including current amount of images currently uploaded a good idea? Also I am thinking that younger the uploads are it should be more popular, for example. image 1 was uploaded 2 months ago and has 65 likes. Image 2 was uploaded 2 days ago and has 65 likes. Image 2 should rank higher because it is newer. How could i do this?

Comment: @Trendee Well , that's a nice point. You can do this simply by rating each image by considering different parameters. For Example: Image1 is having 65 likes and it is 60 days old(2months), Now to rate this image you add 1 point for each like and substract .5 for each day.  In that way ratingOfImage1 = 65-(60*.5) =35  , same way ratingOfImage2 = 65-(2*.5) = 64 (as image2 is 2day old and having 65 likes).  clearly image2 is having more rating so it is more popular. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

How about you prevent an image from being displayed on the 'Most Popular' page until it has a certain number of views?

Comment: This is for my discover page aswell. Otherwise it will never get any views.

Comment: I mean the 'most popular' page. whoops.